# Apply a substracton for each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Wonderware Historian server that captures data. I have to query it with SQL to find difference between the last value of a month and the first value of a month (the value is constantly growing).

To select my data, I did this :

```
SELECT Annees=YEAR(DateTime),Mois=MONTH(DateTime),Value=()
FROM AnalogHistory where TagName = 'OBJECT_TAG_NAME'
AND DateTime >= '01/01/2016 00:00:00' 
AND DateTime <= '24/07/2017 13:53:31';
```

I supposed I will need to use `group` and `order by`, but for now, I'm stuck on how I will get the last and the first value of a month, to subtract it.

Do you know a way to apply the query ?

### EDIT

Actually, I want to perform stats by creating a chart with the "Monthly consumption" (of gas, electricity, water...). The index is constantly growing so I need, for each month, to subtract the first value from the last value.

For example, supposing I have this kind of data :

```
Date                | Index
------              | ------
2017-05-01 00:00:00 | 12
2017-05-01 03:57:00 | 14
2017-05-29 15:00:00 | 97
2017-05-31 22:54:00 | 104
2017-06-01 03:54:00 | 107
2017-06-30 21:54:00 | 211
```

The result for the month of May 2017 must be 104-12 ==> 92
The result for the month of June 2017 must be 211-104 ==> 107

And then, this will be displayed in a bar chart.

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using ?

Comment: Version is 11.0.2100

Comment: Run `Select @@version` and post the result

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64) 
 Feb 10 2012 19:39:15 
 Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
 Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2 <X64> (Build 9200: ) (Hypervisor)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use **[`FIRST_VALUE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql)** window function

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT distinct 
   Annees=YEAR(DateTime),
   Mois=MONTH(DateTime),
   firstRecord = first_value(value)over(partition by YEAR(DateTime),MONTH(DateTime) order by DateTime asc),
   lastRecord = first_value(value)over(partition by YEAR(DateTime),MONTH(DateTime) order by DateTime desc)
FROM AnalogHistory 
where TagName = 'OBJECT_TAG_NAME'
AND DateTime >= '01/01/2016 00:00:00' 
AND DateTime <= '24/07/2017 13:53:31'
)
select 
    Annees,
    Mois, 
    value = isnull(lastRecord,0) - isnull(firstRecord ,0)
from cte
```

---

`Row_Number` approach for older versions

```
;with cte as
(
SELECT 
   Annees=YEAR(DateTime),
   Mois=MONTH(DateTime),
   firstRecord = Row_Number(value)over(partition by YEAR(DateTime),MONTH(DateTime) order by DateTime asc),
   lastRecord = Row_Number(value)over(partition by YEAR(DateTime),MONTH(DateTime) order by DateTime desc)
FROM AnalogHistory 
where TagName = 'OBJECT_TAG_NAME'
AND DateTime >= '01/01/2016 00:00:00' 
AND DateTime <= '24/07/2017 13:53:31'
)
select Annees,Mois,
       min(case when lastRecord = 1 then value end) - 
       min(case when firstRecord = 1 then value end)
From Cte 
Where 1 in (lastRecord,firstRecord )
Group by Annees,Mois
```

Comment: Is the PATITION BY clause necessary? Wouldn't ORDER BY suffice?

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes - It is needed.. did you check the data range.. it is more than one year

Comment: Really interesting, i'll dig on it tomorrow, to check result, but it seems to work fine

Comment: Ok, apparently the OP wants the result for each month, not just for a month.

Comment: Everything is good for what i asking for, thanks. But i experiencing some trouble because of dealing with record and not what database returned to me. In fact, doing this query will make my system return 100 records by regular interval in the specified daterange. But as well, value may be different, like in the very first moment of the month. So i opened this thread, who is like an "enhancement" of this.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45296257/subtraction-for-each-complete-month-for-real-time-database-querying

Answer (score 1):

If the values are ever growing it is much easier to work with the minimum and maximum values of each month instead of first and last (they should be indentical).

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(DateTime) AS Annee, MONTH(DateTime) AS Mois,
    MIN(Value) As MinVal, MAX(Value) As MaxVal,
    MAX(Value) - MIN(Value) As Difference,
FROM AnalogHistory 
WHERE
    TagName = 'OBJECT_TAG_NAME' AND
    DateTime >= '01/01/2016 00:00:00' AND
    DateTime <= '24/07/2017 13:53:31'
GROUP BY YEAR(DateTime), MONTH(DateTime)
ORDER BY YEAR(DateTime), MONTH(DateTime)
```

Comment: I thought about it, but is it possible to perform it with one query ?

Comment: The easiest is to UNION ALL the two queries. This results in 2 records, one with the first value and one with the last value.

Comment: All right, we'll dig on it tomorrow, as i said  to Pரதீப்

Comment: But wit hthe order by asc and desc, i'll need to repeat the query several time. Is it why Pரதீப் used partition ?

Comment: @Littlesquirrel - Absolutely correct.. you have to run this two query for every year-month..

Comment: Another way could be by generating two row_numbers one with `asc` and one with `desc`.. then in outer query using condition aggregation we can get the first and last value of each month

Comment: OP wants *first value of a month & Last value of a month* not Min and Max value of a month.. there is a difference

Comment: Post it in your answer please. (You deserve the upvotes).

Answer (score 0):

This will select the value from your table where the `DateTime` field is within the current month.  Is this what you want?

```
SELECT Value, *
FROM AnalogHistory 
WHERE TagName = 'OBJECT_TAG_NAME'
AND YEAR(DatTime) = YEAR(GETDATE())
AND MONTH(DateTime) = MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Comment: This is not. Actually, i want to perform stats by creating a chart with the "Monthly consumption" (of Gaz, electricity, water...). The index is constantly growing so i need, for each month, to substract the last value and the first value.

Comment: @Littlesquirrel It is very difficult to understand what you're asking.  Can you post some sample data - and your expected results.  If you do, I will provide a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQL like this one

```
 WITH cte_min_date 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY Year([datetime]) * 100 + Month([datetime]) 
                    ORDER BY [datetime]) AS rn, 
                [datetime], 
                [value] 
         FROM   analoghistory 
         WHERE  tagname = 'OBJECT_TAG_NAME' 
                AND datetime >= '01/01/2016 00:00:00' 
                AND datetime <= '24/07/2017 13:53:31'), 
     cte_max_date 
     AS (SELECT Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY Year([datetime]) * 100 + Month([datetime]) 
                    ORDER BY [datetime] DESC) AS rn, 
                [datetime], 
                [value] 
         FROM   analoghistory 
         WHERE  tagname = 'OBJECT_TAG_NAME' 
                AND datetime >= '01/01/2016 00:00:00' 
                AND datetime <= '24/07/2017 13:53:31') 
SELECT a.[datetime], 
       b.[datetime], 
       Year(a.[datetime]) * 100 + Month(a.[datetime]), 
       b.[value] - a.[value] AS [Value] 
FROM   cte_min_date a 
       INNER JOIN cte_max_date b 
               ON Year(a.[datetime]) * 100 + Month(a.[datetime]) = 
                             Year(b.[datetime]) * 100 + Month(b.[datetime]) 
                  AND a.rn = b.rn 
WHERE  a.rn = 1
```