# Subtraction for each complete month for real time database querying

Tags: sql, sql-server, partition

I have a question, a bit different of [Apply a substracton for each month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283415/apply-a-substracton-for-each-month/)

About these SQL :

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        Annees = YEAR(DateTime),
        Mois = MONTH(DateTime),
        firstRecord = first_value(value) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(DateTime), MONTH(DateTime) ORDER BY DateTime ASC),
        lastRecord = first_value(value) OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(DateTime), MONTH(DateTime) ORDER BY DateTime DESC)
    FROM 
        AnalogHistory 
    WHERE
        TagName = 'A_000000000000000000000000000058.PV_Kw'
        AND DateTime >= '01/01/2016 00:00:00' 
        AND DateTime <= '24/07/2017 13:53:31'
)
SELECT
    Annees, Mois, 
    value = isnull(lastRecord, 0) - isnull(firstRecord, 0)
FROM
    cte


SELECT 
    YEAR(DateTime) AS Annee, MONTH(DateTime) AS Mois,
    MIN(Value) As MinVal, MAX(Value) As MaxVal,
    MAX(Value) - MIN(Value) As Difference
FROM 
    AnalogHistory 
WHERE
    TagName = 'A_000000000000000000000000000058.PV_Kw' AND
    DateTime >= '01/01/2016 00:00:00' AND
    DateTime <= '24/07/2017 13:53:31'
GROUP BY 
    YEAR(DateTime), MONTH(DateTime)
ORDER BY 
    YEAR(DateTime), MONTH(DateTime)
```

They are all good for what I'm asking for. But for now, it's a bit different.

As I said, I have a historian database, and this kind of query will return 100 rows, spaced by the same interval, so for the query, I will get:

```
2017-03-31 07:39:04.1310000
2017-04-06 01:57:47.4740000
2017-04-11 20:16:30.8180000
...
```

This is problematic because the value for 2017-04-06 01:57:47.4740000 might not be the same as the value the 2017-04-01 00:00:00.0000000, and the result the output is false.

So basically, I'll need to take the same query, but applying it for the very first moment of a month and the very last moment of a month.

Any ideas?

### EDIT

I have to select for each month the first moment and the last moment, and with these, i need to query my database to get the corresponding value and substract it.

So what i want is getting value for :

```
2017-03-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 12
2017-03-31 23:59:59.9999999 | 24
2017-04-01 00:00:00.0000000 | 24
2017-04-30 23:59:59.9999999 | 78
...
```

instead of :

```
2017-03-31 07:39:04.1310000 | 23
2017-04-06 01:57:47.4740000 | 38
2017-04-11 20:16:30.8180000 | 42
...
```

The historian database will be able to retrieve me value as well, so **don't have to worry about having data for the first and last moment of month**

With these value, i need to substract it and retrieve it, so this might be :

```
Year | Month | Value
2017 | 03    | 12
2017 | 04    | 54
...
```

It's kind of difficult to explain well, but the database i'm trying to querying is using SQL as an interface to read the data. In fact, the real database in time based, so i will store each value of a object among he will get value. So i can query at any moment, the database will be able to retrieve me something.

Here is an exemple of output :

[image: Database query example]

I'm not able to retrieve anything else about the table design. All i know is that the TagName condition is mandatory.

Comment: Seriously, maybe a little Googling effort on your part, e.g. "sql server start of month"?

Comment: You already use `first_value` to calculate the first/last value, what else do you want.

Comment: @dnoeth, he wants us to write a query that will return 1st day of the month

Comment: In SQL Server 2012 and newer there is function [`EOMONTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql).

Comment: I really dislike this kind of questions. Having us read irrelevant code, sending us to read other questions, and yet fail to provide the **relevant** data. A good sql query should contain a clear explanation of the problem, sample data as ddl+dml, desired results, and your current best attempt. Anything other then that is simply noise.

Comment: You're absolutely wrong Alex. As i said, i have to work on a query that will substract value FOR the last moment of a month and the first moment of a month. And as well, sorry but the SQL is not my heart of job, so i'm able to make some select, but when we are coming at "partition" and things like this, it become quite difficult to me, as long as i try to understand.

Comment: @ZoharPeled As you said, i edited the question

Comment: Please edit to add the table create statement and some insert statement for sample data. Also, I don't really understand what is the desired output.

Comment: I give up. I hope someone will answer this question, I'm not going to.